# Management fee increase

Tags: united-kingdom, competition

My house comes with a covenant to pay a maintenance charge for some nearby land. Part of this charge is a fee paid to the managing agent for the service of doing the management.

This year they have stated that the management fee will increase by 5%. Their explanation was:

> All our management fees have increased by 5% this year, in line with other managing agents.

The [Competition Act 1998](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/41) Section 2 says:

> [...] agreements between undertakings, decisions by associations of undertakings or concerted practices which—
>
> (a)may affect trade within the United Kingdom, and
>
> (b)have as their object or effect the prevention, restriction or distortion of competition within the United Kingdom,
>
> are prohibited unless they are exempt in accordance with the provisions of this Part.
>
> (2)Subsection (1) applies, in particular, to agreements, decisions or practices which—
>
> (a)directly or indirectly fix purchase or selling prices or any other trading conditions;

Am I right in thinking that an increase above inflation "in line with other managing agents" is a "concerted practice" to "fix selling prices" and hence a violation of the law?

Comment: I think "in line with other managing agents" means what the managing agent thinks other managing agents are charging - or what the agent wants you to believe other agents are charging. I don't think it means they are admitting to being in a cartel.

Answer (score 1):

### No

The prohibition is on competitors making an agreement to fix prices. Changing your prices to match your competition is not making an agreement.

Answer (score 1):

No, if I understand your circumstances and the OFT's *[Agreements and concerted practices - Understanding competition law](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/284396/oft401.pdf)* (2004):

> In considering if a concerted practice exists, the OFT will follow
>   relevant Community precedents established under Article 81 [of the EC
>   treaty]. The OFT will need to establish that the parties, even if they
>   did not enter into an agreement, knowingly substituted cooperation
>   between them for the risks of competition.
>
> The following are examples of factors which the OFT may consider in
>   establishing if a concerted practice exists:
>
> - whether the parties knowingly entered into practical co-operation
> - whether behaviour in the market is influenced as a result of direct    or indirect contact between undertakings
> - whether parallel behaviour is a result of contact between undertakings leading to conditions of competition which do not
>     correspond to normal conditions of the market
> - the structure of the relevant market and the nature of the product involved
> - the number of undertakings in the market and, where there are only a few undertakings, whether they have similar cost structures and
>     outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The third bullet in your quote may be relevant because I don't know how the managing agents would know what each other's price increases are without some kind of contact; our price is published to the householders but not (AFAIK) elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulJohnson How do you know the managing agents know each other's prices? They could be 'trying it on' - just attempting to justify an increase in price to you. You could ask them how they know - and their reply might constitute evidence of concerted practice.

Comment: I'm waiting for a reply to that question. In the meantime I'm asking here what it would mean if their words were taken at face value.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I was going to suggest calling the OFT, then I remembered it was closed in 2014 and its responsibilities divided among a number of different entities. I don't know which entity could help with this query.